# SQL Column Search Question (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column varchar(70) in one of my table where I store space separated tags:

```
Id  Tags 
1   Baby Kids Learning Alphabets 
2   Kids Baby 
3   Comedy Movie Fun
100 Kids Learning Alphabets
500 Kids Baby
```

I perform search on the column:
  Get all ids where we have Baby Kids and Alphabets in the tags

I can do where Tags like '%Baby%' or Tags like '%Kids%' or Tags like '%Alphabets %'
  Select query isslow when there are large # of rows. But add\delete\edit is always very fast.

So I added another table Called Tags where I store the tags alphabetically like:

```
  Tag        Id
  Alphabets  1
  Alphabets  100
  Baby       1
  Baby       2
  Baby       500
  Comedy     3
  Kids       1
```

This make the searching faster, buy update\delete\insert painful.

Is my design right for future growth?

How should you design this tags column?

Thanks for reading

**EDIT:**
**All I am trying to pull is the list of related ids. Basically find all ids having the given tags or tag. Like on this question, you see "Related Questions" on the right. That is what I am trying to get.**

Answer (score 1):

You will really have to analyze which aspects of your site will grow and what your goals are.  Will there be tons of inserts?  Will there be tons of tags? Do you need to answer the question "How many questions have the tag 'Alphabet'?"  I hate "it depends" answers, but it really does depend on your goals and expectations.

Comment: I have answers for all of qs. There will be millions of tags. Just consider it is a public sharing site. If there are 10 millions rows and each has 5 tags, then that is 50M tags. So tons of tags will be there. I must select give me all ids where we have Alphabets and Learning

Comment: It sounds like it is likely that tags will be your bottleneck so they should be fast.  Your latest approach seems better to me for that reason.  You can also consider keeping a cached count on the Tag table in case you need to answer the question "How many times is this tag used?" That will of course be another thing to do on insert/update/delete, but may pay big dividends in the long run if you expect to be showing a tag cloud on every page view.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I recommend:

Create 2 new tables.  One simply stores the name of the tag

```
  Tag        Id
  Alphabets  1
  Baby       2
  Comedy     3
  Kids       4
  Learning   5
  Alphabets  6
```

The second one will link the tag to the entry in the first table

```
  main_id    tag_id
  1          2
  1          4
  1          5
  1          6
  100        4
  100        5
  100        6
```

Then you can simply search with a join between the tables.  It will be a LOT faster.  Be sure to include the appropriate indexes.

Comment: I see zero advantage with this over my design. I am saving a join and easy insert\update\delete.

Comment: Since you asked about for future design- this would be the best way to go.  If you decide later to add a subcategory and change one of your category names this would make your life simpler.  Take "baby" for example.  If you decide in the future to make different categories of "infant" and "toddler", and maybe make all the current "baby" ones into "infant", you would have to update every single row in your design where it says "baby".  With mine, you just have to update the category table for the 1 entry and you are done.

Comment: It is also good design see http://www.sqlteam.com/article/database-design-and-modeling-fundamentals (search many-to-many) and also look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization or google search database normalization

Comment: Rayman, for tags, I am not planning a subcategory. Thanks for your point though. Upvoting.

Comment: Yeah you may not plan it, but you never know :)  Basically what you have here is a "many-to-many" relationship.  There are 3 kinds (1-to-many, 1-to-1, and many-to-many), and this is how I learned in my database class to design them.

Comment: @Projapati if you're seriously going to have *millions of tags* as you stated, normalization, like this, will pay off the effort required to code.  Take in account in larger you don't optimize by saving joins, you optimize by analyzing query plans, making extensive use of indexes and remembering unique indexes in general are more eligible and provide better performance.

Comment: @rayman yeah, why would you ever want to use a relational database in its relational capacity... :sigh: